# Unity3d iOS build exportArchive IPA size

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

There are several questions are already on Unity3d IPA sizes but I found none that properly solves the issue.

The problem is that I have a 24mg IPA if I export IPA through XCode GUI and I get a 160mg one if I export with the command line.

The steps:

- create project from Unity using default iOS settings
- open in Xcode 7.3.1, select *Product* -> *Archive*

Now, through the GUI:

- open *Organizer*, select archive, Export, Save for Enterprise Deployment, done

IPA with 24mg

Through command line:

- get path to the archive generated by xcode from Organizer (*Show in Finder*)
- Run `xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ~/Library/etc/etc/Unity-iPhone.xcarchive -exportPath build/Unity-iPhone -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "My Provisioning Profile"`

This gives me a 160mg IPA...

```
$ ls -lh
total 382480
-rw-r--r--  1 iz  staff   163M Jul 26 15:28 cmdline.ipa
-rw-r--r--  1 iz  staff    23M Jul 26 15:28 gui.ipa
```

Unzipping the IPA files and comparing trees (with `find . -exec ls -lh {} \;` and `diff`):

```
$ diff gui.txt cmdline.txt 
55,56c54
< -rw-r--r--  1 iz  staff   416B Jul 26 12:15 ./Payload/childplayground.app/archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent
< -rwxr-xr-x  1 iz  staff    30M Jul 26 12:23 ./Payload/childplayground.app/childplayground
---
> -rwxr-xr-x  1 iz  staff   270M Jul 26 12:27 ./Payload/childplayground.app/childplayground
```

This clearly shows that the only size difference is within the main binary itself. Plus the GUI generated IPA contains this `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` file that the command line doesn't...

Any hints on what I can change in command line to be able to get the same IPA size?

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `archive` argument at the end of that `xcodebuild` command line?

Comment: that was the previous step (archiving), done through the GUI (in this example). solved anyway, posting answer now...

Comment: fyi, also asked here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309133/app-size-increased-drammatically-from-exported-ipa-to-itunes-connect#

Answer (score 1):

I guess I shouldn't have ignore the *deprecated* warning and used `-exportOptionsPlist` instead.

That generated an IPA with the same 24mg as the GUI.

For completeness, the `exportOptions.plist` file used was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>method</key>
        <string>enterprise</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

And command line:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ~/Library/etc/etc/Unity-iPhone.xcarchive -exportPath build/Unity-iPhone -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist
```

Removed `exportFormat` and `exportProvisioningProfile` and used `exportOptionsPlist` instead