# App size increased drammatically from exported IPA to ITunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I loaded  xcode from Unity.
When I export an IPA file then the file size is 37 MB. However when I submit to Itunes for app review, the app size is 128 in the UC (universal) and 77 in the other devices.

What is the reason for this major increase? Is there anything I can do to cut down this size as I know my app should not be this big anyways (the android version is 30)

PS: When I exported IPA, I did nt include bitcode. but when I submited, I checked this box. I have no idea if I should or should not. I just left it to default

Thank you

Comment: see solution idea to add export options plist, here ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593012/unity3d-ios-build-exportarchive-ipa-size